# Nuxt.js: pass keep-alive-props to root nuxt component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

As documentation says `<nuxt-child/> accepts keep-alive and keep-alive-props`. Is there any way to pass keep-alive props to `<nuxt/>` component?

`<nuxt keep-alive :keep-alive-props="{max: 3}"/>` seems take no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be included in nuxt 2.4 release. I made a fix to make this work.

Relevant PR -> https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/4610